# Get full qualifying column name in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-cli, cassandra-jdbc

Below is my sample database schema in Cassandra.

```
CREATE TYPE TypeAddress(
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 INT,
    Column3 INT
);

CREATE TABLE TablePersonInfo(
    ColumnA INT,
    ColumnB INT,
    TypeAddress_ FROZEN<TypeAddress>
);

CREATE KeySpace KSName;
```

I want full qualifying names for the columns.

```
e.g. 
KSName.TablePersonInfo.TypeAddress.Column1
KSName.TablePersonInfo.TypeAddress.Column2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? The schema defines the fully-qualified names. The only odd thing I see here is that you're defining a keyspace "after" the type and table.

Comment: I have embedded information like Address(using TYPE) in the main table. So I am trying to get the full path for the respected columns.

Comment: In what context? cqlsh gives you `DESC TABLE` and `DESC TYPE`. Some drivers also present a schema metadata API you could use to traverse the tables and types. We would need to understand your goal to provide a useful answer.